# Automate Entering choices for a mvn script

Tags: cmd

I have a maven script used for my project which asks multiple times for user choice.I want to automate the choices entered by making a script where i hard code the choice options.Is there a way to do that?Please help.
Fresh to Scripting.

Comment: You should clarify your problem to something directly answerable, or post your current solution that is not working.

Comment: Suppose i want to build a basic Maven project architecture using Maven Archetype wizard plugin.While that plugin runs it asks for various choice like module name and various yes and no answers .How to automate this choice entring using a script

Answer (score 0):

Suppose i want to build a basic Maven project architecture using Maven Archetype wizard plugin.While that plugin runs it asks for various choice like module name and various yes and no answers .How to automate this choice entring using a script